# Autofac ASP.NET MVC5: mix using Resolve<T> from controller and class library

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

My question is in Autofac (SimpleInjector just work) how do I create static class that can easily access from both MVC controller and class library, there are many of similar questions but I still didn't get answer I am seeking.

I am trying to use Autofac resolver from class library behind MVC and get error "No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. "

Ok this is start of story. I have singleton class EngineContext that hold my diContainer and in my class library where I am trying to use EngineContext.DiContainer.GetInstance() it will get this error because I called resolver from singlton instance class.

I did my research to work around different way but with no luck. When I use DepedencyResolver.Current.GetService it say HttpContext error then I tried to pass DependencyResolver.Current from global.asax but it always return null when resolve my request type.

Also tried 
builder.RegisterType().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("child")
using (var lifetime = container.BeginLifetimeScope("child")) {
But same it says No scope with a Tag "child" scope blah blah.

Currently this work in my Controller constructor and Static Class calling. but it's not work if I call resolver from a inside controller method or class library from lower layer. Below is my code

MVC startup

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(ModuleConfig), "Start")]
[assembly: ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(ModuleConfig), "Stop")]
namespace NexusCore.Admin
{
    public class ModuleConfig
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            EngineConfig();
        }

        public static void Stop()
        {
        }

        private static void EngineConfig()
        {
            // Dependancy Injection initialize
            EngineContext.Instance.Initialize(new AutofacFactory(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.RegisterControllers(typeof (MvcApplication).Assembly);
                    // Unit of Work
                    builder.RegisterType<ContentContext>().As<IContentContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
                    builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
                    builder.RegisterType<WebErrorHandlerFactory>().As<IErrorHandlerFactory>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

                },
                new AutofacRegisterAdmin(),
                container => DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container))));
        }
    }
}
```

EngineContext

```
public class EngineContext : IEngine
{
    private static IEngine _instance;

    public static IEngine Instance
    {
        get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new EngineContext()); }
    }

    private IDiContainer _diContainer;
    private ICurrentUserProvider _currentUserProvider;

    public IDiContainer DiContainer
    {
        get
        {
            if (_diContainer == null)
            {
                var error = ErrorAdapter.ModelState.AddModelError("", "",
                    logCode: LogCode.CriticalEngineDiContainerNotInitialized);
                throw new Exception(error.ErrorMessage);                    
            }
            return _diContainer;
        }
    }

    public ICurrentUserProvider CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            if (_currentUserProvider == null)
            {
                var error = ErrorAdapter.ModelState.AddModelError("", "",
                    logCode: LogCode.CriticalEngineCurrentUserProviderNotInitialized);
                throw new Exception(error.ErrorMessage);
            }
            return _currentUserProvider;
        }
    }

    public void Initialize(IDiContainerFactory diContainerFactory)
    {
        DiContainerInitialize(diContainerFactory);
        CurrentUserProviderInitialize();
    }

    private void DiContainerInitialize(IDiContainerFactory diContainerFactory)
    {
        _diContainer = diContainerFactory.Create();            
    }

    private void CurrentUserProviderInitialize()
    {
        _currentUserProvider = _diContainer.GetInstance<ICurrentUserProvider>();
    }

}
```

Di Factory

```
public class AutofacFactory : IDiContainerFactory
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public AutofacFactory(Action<ContainerBuilder> preRegister, IDiRegister register, Action<IContainer> resolver)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        preRegister(builder);
        // init register
        Register(builder, register);
        _container = builder.Build();
        resolver(_container);
    }

    private void Register(ContainerBuilder builder, IDiRegister register)
    {
        register.SetBuilder(builder);
        register.Register();
    }

    public IDiContainer Create()
    {
        return new AutofacContainer(_container);
    }
}
```

Di Container

```
public class AutofacContainer : IDiContainer
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public AutofacContainer(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public TService GetInstance<TService>() where TService : class
    {
        using (var scope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            return scope.Resolve<TService>(); // change this line many times.
        }
    }
}
```

Where is not work

```
public class ComponentServices : IComponentServices
{
    public IInstallationService InstallationService
    {
        get { return GetInstance<IInstallationService>(); }
    }

    public IMembershipService MembershipService
    {
        get { return GetInstance<IMembershipService>(); }
    }

    private T GetInstance<T>() where T : class
    {
        return EngineContext.Instance.DiContainer.GetInstance<T>(); // Not work in class library
    }

}
```

In Controller, if I use membshipService directly it will just work fine

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly Infrasructure.Security.IAuthenticationManager _userManager;
    //private readonly IComponentServices _services;
    private readonly IMembershipService _memberhsip;

    public AccountController(Infrasructure.Security.IAuthenticationManager userManager, IMembershipService membership)
    {}
```

In Controller, if I use ComponenetServices then use _services.MembershipServices it will get error. Because ComponentServices try to call EngineContext.DiContainer.GetInstanct() then it to No scope with a Tag matching "AutofacWebRequest" error will come back.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found purpose of ComponentService can be simply resolved by using property Injection, I have over complicated it.

```
public class ComponentServices : IComponentServices
{

    public IInstallationService InstallationService { get; set; }
    public IMembershipService MembershipService { get; set; }
}
```

only 1 line need to modified then Dependency Resolver will inject them automatically.

```
        Builder.RegisterType<ComponentServices>().As<IComponentServices>().InstancePerLifetimeScope().PropertiesAutowired();
```

My bad, too confuse.